# TypeError: undefined for array in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use an array defined as a const in React, and pass this array in my App function. However, when I try to use it, I am getting a "TypeError: products is undefined" (in regards to `<li> {products[0].id}</li>`).

Any help would be much appreciated. I have attached my App.js file, and stripped the application down to it's bare to attempt to single out the issue.

The link to the complete project can be found here: https://github.com/coopertim13/ProblematicReact

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const products = [
  {id: 'P1000', name:'UGG', category: 'Cool'}
]

const App = (props) => {
  const {products} = props

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li> {products[0].id}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App products = {products}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what you need to know. Your prop on `App` is called units, but you're trying to destructure `products` from it, which is `undefined`.

Change `const {products} = props` to `const {units} = props` and then change `<li> {products[0].id}</li>` to `<li> {units[0].id}</li>`.

You could also alias it like so, `const {units: products} = props` and leave the rest of your code.

### Edit

After pulling down the repo, there are several issues I found.

```
// App.js
// Change the code to this,

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Unit = ({ unit }) => {
    const [title, setCase] = useState(unit.title)

    const goUp = () => setCase(String(title).toUpperCase())
    const goDown = () => setCase(String(title).toLowerCase())

    return (
        <div>
            <span>
                {unit.code} - {title}: {unit.offering}
            </span>
            <button onClick={goUp}>Up</button>
            <button onClick={goDown}>Down</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const App = ({ units }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {units.map(unit => (
                    <Unit key={unit.code} unit={unit} />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

In index.js, change it to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

const units = [
    { code: 'COMP1010', title: 'Fundamentals of Computer Science', offering: ['S1', 'S2'] },
    { code: 'COMP1750', title: 'Introduction to Business Information Systems', offering: ['S1'] },
    { code: 'COMP2110', title: 'Web Technology', offering: ['S1', 'S2'] },
    { code: 'COMP2750', title: 'Applications Modelling and Development', offering: ['S1'] },
    { code: 'MMCC2045', title: 'Interactive Web Design', offering: ['S2'] },
    { code: 'COMP3120', title: 'Advanced Web Development', offering: ['S2'] },
    { code: 'COMP3130', title: 'Mobile Application Development', offering: ['S1'] }
]

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App units={units} />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)

serviceWorker.unregister()
```

What was happening is this: `<App />` was expecting the units to be passed to it so it could pass it to `<Unit />`. However, in index.js, you weren't passing in the `units` prop. So, I moved the units array to index and passed it in and it worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue. I am now just getting `TypeError: units is undefined`

Comment: Have edited my question accordingly, however the issue still remains

Comment: @CoopDaddio what happens if you remove `const {products} = props`? It should use the products array outside of the component. Does that work?

Comment: I have been learning using this resource https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/rendering_a_collection_modules and this is _**not**_ how they recommend implementing it

Comment: I have also found that this implementation means I'm not able to pass data into a separate function as a prop

Comment: @CoopDaddio considering your code works in the demo Bhuwan provided, it's really impossible to say. If the props aren't being respected, maybe it's something to do with your build tools and JSX.  If you have a repo you can share, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `const products = props.units` instead.

Comment: On line 9? Unfortunately this did not fix the issue

Comment: @CoopDaddio Here is working link https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cartwright-1i0rt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: That may be the case, but unfortunately still not working on my local machine - maybe a much larger issue is at bay